# Documenting Unknown Data Type In Method Comments for PHP

Tags: php, types, comments

I have a method in a class that sanitizes data that will be input into a mysql database.  It takes two parameters, $data of unknown data type and $html_allowed of bool type.  The data type of the $data variable will not initially be known by the method.  In the comments, how do I document an unknow data type?  Right now my comments look like this:

```
/**
 *  Sanitizes database input to prevent sql injections.
 *  
 *  @param unknown $data    
 *  @param bool html_allowed
 *  returns unknown $data
 */
```

Is this ok, or is there a better/standardized way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@mixed` if the argument can be of multiple types.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't run across that one before.